# Can Tkinter recognize which header was selected in treeview?

Tags: tkinter, header, treeview

I am trying create a GUI where someone can upload an excel file and then allow a user to select a header from that file.

I am new to Tkinter and have previously written this in Python but would like to switch to a GUI.

I have been able to get Tkinter to upload and display an excel file chosen by the user but need help with how to recognize which header the user clicks on in treeview. I have created a frame that will display that treeview of the excel file. The prompt will ask the user to click on the header of the column they would like to filter by.

Here is the working code that I have written thus far.

`   from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, Text, ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

```
root = Tk()
root.title('GUI Test Run')
root.geometry("800x600")

#create a frame that will contain the data of the excel file selected
my_frame = Frame(root)

#create scrollbar
my_scrollbar = Scrollbar(my_frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
my_frame.pack(pady=20)

#add some style to treeview
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("default")

#create a treeview
my_tree = ttk.Treeview(my_frame, xscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)

#configure scrollbar
my_scrollbar.config(command=my_tree.xview)
my_scrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

#create file open function
def file_open():
    selectedFile = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select File")
    if selectedFile:
        try:
            selectedFile = r"{}".format(selectedFile)
            df = pd.read_excel(selectedFile)
        except ValueError:
            my_label.config(text="File could not be opened... try again!")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            my_label.config(text="File could not be found... try again!")

    clear_tree() 

    #Set up new treeview
    my_tree["column"] = list(df.columns) #will find the column headers of the spreadsheet
    my_tree["show"] = "headings" #we want to show the headings

    #loop through column list for headers
    for column in my_tree["column"]:
        my_tree.heading(column, text=column)

    #put data in treeview. take the rows of data that panda read in
    # and convert to a numpy array and then convert that to a list
    df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist()

    #now just loop through the list and spit it out onto the screen
    for row in df_rows:
        my_tree.insert("", "end", values=row)

def clear_tree():
    my_tree.delete(*my_tree.get_children()) 

#add a menu
my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu)

#button
selectFileButton = Button(root, text="Select File", compound = CENTER, command=file_open).place(anchor=NW)

#pack the treeview
my_tree.pack(pady=30)

#create a blank label for the errors
my_label = Label(root, text='')
my_label.pack(pady=20)

#Create an entry box for the selected fields
selection_frame = Frame(root)
selection_frame.pack(pady=20)
sh = Label(selection_frame, text="Selected Header") 
sh.grid(row=0,column=0)
selected_header = Entry(selection_frame)
selected_header.grid(row=1,column=0)

#create binding click function
def selectHeader(e): 
    selected_header.delete(0, END)
    selected = my_tree.focus()
    values = my_tree.item(selected, 'values')
    selected_header.insert(0, values)
    temp_label.config(text=values)

#Binding
my_tree.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", selectHeader)

temp_label = Label(root, text="")
temp_label.pack(pady=20)

quitButton = Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.quit)
quitButton.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
`
```

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve] that uses some dummy data rather than requiring an external file. Also, have you read through the documentation on the Treeview widget? There is a method named `identify` that you might find useful.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have edited the code to the working code that will upload an excel file and prompt you to select the header.

Comment: I did look into `identify` and tried to add it into my code but it would get a __tkinter.TclError: Item #2 not found_ error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure about the question. But as far as I understand your concern I've found a tutorial on [`youtube`][1].

````
    import openpyxl as xl
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter import filedialog




    def getHeader(ws):
        mylist =[]
        for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1,max_col=ws.max_column, max_row = 1):
            for cell in row:
                mylist.append(cell.value)
        return mylist

    def getBody_Dict_List(ws,header_list):
        masterList = []
        masterDict = []

        for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2,max_col=ws.max_column, max_row = ws.max_row):    
            myList = []
            myDict = {}
            for i, cell in enumerate(row):
                myList.append(cell.value)
                myDict[header_list[i]] = cell.value
            masterList.append(myList)
            masterDict.append(myDict)

        return masterDict,masterList


#Front End
    def order_by(a):
        bodyDict.sort(key = lambda key:key[a])
        insertIntoTreeView()

    def clearTreeView():
        mytree.delete(*mytree.get_children())

    def insertIntoTreeView():

        clearTreeView()
        for i in range(len(bodyDict)):
            data = list(bodyDict[i].values())
            mytree.insert("",'end',values = (data))

    def upload():
        global headerList
        global bodyDict
        selectedFile = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",title="Select File")
        wb = xl.load_workbook(str(selectedFile))
        ws = wb.active
        headerList = getHeader(ws)
        bodyDict, bodyList = getBody_Dict_List(ws,headerList)

        mytree['column']= headerList
        for i in headerList:
            mytree.column(i,width = 80)
            mytree.heading(i,text=i.capitalize(),command=lambda a=i: order_by(a))

        mytree["show"] = "headings"


        insertIntoTreeView()





    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("600x600")

    myFrame = Frame(root,width=500,height=500,bg="red")
    myFrame.pack()

#Adding My Tree view in myFrame
    mytree = ttk.Treeview(myFrame)
    mytree.pack()




    button = Button(root,text = "Upload Excel",command = upload)
    button.pack()





    root.mainloop()```


   

  [1]: https://youtu.be/afLEz6ILe14
````

Comment: Thank you @prince-shrestha for the tutorial. I will take a look at it and see if I can make it work. Long video but it seems that there is about 30 minutes of no video at the beginning. I appreciate your help!